# Why does the objectivity rule out the convexity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-theory

In the famous work "Ball J M. Convexity conditions and existence theorems in nonlinear elasticity[J]. Archive for rational mechanics and Analysis, 1976, 63(4): 337-403", it was mentioned that the material indifference principle will rule out the possibility of the convexity of the energy function. In details, if $S=S(F)$ is a function of an invertible function $F$ and $S(F)=S(OF)$ for all orthogonal matrix $O$, then $S$ can not be convex unless $S$ is a quadratic function of $F$. Could anyone tell me how to prove this?

In addition, if $S=S(F)$ is rank-one convex and we know that $S=S(F) = W(F^TF)$, then is $W$ a convex function?